# Valuation of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My paper defines a valuation on a Ring $R$ to be a map $v:R-\{0\} \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is an ordered abelian group. This map has the following properties;

1.$v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$

2.$v(a+b)\geq min\{v(a),v(b)\}$
(note this is missing the usual conditon wich grants equality if $v(a) \neq v(b)$)

My question is the following: Let $w:R[x]-0_{R[x]} \rightarrow A$ by;
$$w(\sum_{i=0}^nr_ix^i)=min_{0\leq i \leq n}v(r_i)$$

and I'm to show this is a valuation.  I can easily show property 2 but I cannot show property 1. I'm starting to doubt if it is possible; I wrote out some examples and I don't see how I can get anything other than a lower bound for a $w(fg)$. A hint or even confirmation that this is solvable would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to assume $ab\ne 0$ in condition 1 and $a+b\ne 0$ in condition 2.  If $R$ is an integral domain, then condition 1 is OK as is.  You can make condition 2 OK by taking $v(0)=\infty$, where $\infty>x$ for all $x\in A$.

Conditions 1 & 2 imply $v(a+b)=\min \{v(a),v(b)\}$ if $v(a)\ne v(b)$.  To see this, first note $v(1)=0$, whence $v(-1)+v(-1)=v(1)=0$, whence $v(-1)=0$, and so $v(-r)=v(-1)+v(r)=v(r)$.  Now suppose $v(a)>v(b)$: then $v(b)=v(a+b+-a)\ge \min \{v(a+b),v(-a)\}$.  Since $v(-a)=v(a)>v(b)$, this implies $v(a+b)\le v(b)$.  As $v(b)\le v(a+b)$, this shows $v(b)=v(a+b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is an integral domain, your formula for $w$ does yield a valuation.  Here is a hint toward proving condition 1 holds.  We will use the observation in my comment that $v(a+b)=\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ if $v(a)\ne v(b)$.

Let $f=\sum_i r_ix^i$ and $g=\sum_j s_jx^j$ and suppose $w(f)=v(r_p)$, $w(g)=v(s_q)$, where $p,q$ are as small as possible.  In $fg$, the coefficient $t_{p+q}$ of $x^{p+q}$ is a sum containing the product $r_ps_q$ and other products $r_is_j$ where either $i<p$ or $j<q$.  Show $v(r_is_j)>v(r_ps_q)$ for those terms, and so $v(t_{p+q})=v(r_ps_q)=v(r_p)+v(s_q)$.  Show that no coefficient of another $t^k$ can be smaller than $v(r_p)+v(s_q)$.  Conclude that $w(fg)=v(r_p)+v(s_q)=w(f)+w(g)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I need to add infinity to $A$?

Comment: @Muselive  Unless $v(0)$ is defined, the condition $v(a+b)\ge\min\{v(a),v(b)\}$ needs to have the extra assumption that $a+b\ne 0$ added.